# CSS animate a div with absolute positioning from left 0 to right 0

Tags: css, css-animations

Consider this sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfabulich/ncbzz5zu/3/

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from { background-color: red; left: 0; }
  to { background-color: blue; right: 0; }
}

.animated {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

</style>
<div class=container>
<div class=animated>
</div></div>
```

Expected: The red rectangle should smoothly animate from left to right as the color changes from red to blue.

Actual: In Chrome/Firefox, the red rectangle slowly changes color to purple, then teleports from left to right without animating, and then slowly changes from purple to blue. In Safari, the rectangle appears on the right and never moves from there, while animating from red to blue.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? (I need to fix it in CSS… no JS, no jQuery.)

Comment: You can not "animate" from one _property_ to another; you animate the _value_ of a property. In this case, with the element being 20% wide, you could simply animate left from 0 to 80%.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to animate one property or the other. You can just animate left and either use `left: calc(100% - elemWidth)` (where `elemWidth` is the width of the element) or `left: 100%; transform: translateX(-100%);` if the width of the element is unknown.

Also need to animate background color.

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.animated {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 background-color: red;
 animation: 3s linear 0s slide infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from { left: 0; }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
<div class=animated>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes slide {
  from { left: 0;}
  to { left: 80%; } // edit: actually endpoint should point to left:100% minus width of the element so in your case 100%-20% = 80%. In case of width of the element in px use CSS calc like:  left: calc(100% - ##px);
}
```

Simply when you used `right` you told transition to change totally different property. That is why you were jumping between `left: 0` what is left side of your screen to `right: 0` what is right edge of your screen.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me understand what went wrong here?

Comment: This moves the box outside of the parent on the right side. And it doesn't change the background color.

Comment: updated the code. @MichaelCoker OP wanted to clarify only transition from left to right, color was working fine for him. Even his jsfiddle includes only the element movement part.

Comment: better :) the background part is in their post. *"Expected: The red rectangle should smoothly animate from left to right as the color changes from red to blue."*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start animating property `left`, but then replace it with `right` in the end of animation, that's why it jumps. You should keep animating the same property to get the step by step animation progression.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from { background-color: red; left: 0; }
  to { background-color: blue; left: 80%; }
}

.animated {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="animated"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { background-color: red; left: 0; }
  100% { background-color: blue; left: 100%; margin-left: -20%; }
}

.animated {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

</style>
<div class=container>
<div class=animated>
</div></div>
```

see this snippet...

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/ncbzz5zu/11/

And this is the fix for it:

```
@keyframes slide {
  from { background-color: red;
         left:0%;}
  to { background-color:blue; 
        left:80%;}
}
```

Basically, the animation didnt know what to do since you specified the initial left property but not the target value. It animated from `left:0` to `left:initial`. Right fulfills a similar function to left but its still another property.