# How to move the text in a div in square path using CSS animation?

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag and its width and height are 500px,500px respectively and some text is there also. I want to move this text in this div like "bottom left" to "bottom right"  and "bottom right" to "top right" and "top right" to "top left" and "top left" to "bottom left" using CSS animations

```
<div style="height:500px;width:500px">
  <h3>Hai</h3>
</div>
```

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the outer div to `position: relative;` and the inner div to `position: absolute; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0;` to position it in the bottom left corner.

You can then give the text an animation lasting 4s which goes on forever like this:

```
animation: change 4s normal 0s infinite;
```

For the animation itself, I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted. If you wanted the the text to appear in the different corners, you can use this:

```
@keyframes change {
    /* Change from bottom left to bottom right a quarter way through*/
  25% { top: auto; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: auto; }
    /* Change from bottom right to top right half way through*/
  50% { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: auto; left: auto; }
    /* Change from top right to top left three quarters through*/
  75% { top: 0; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0; }
    /* Change from top left to bottom left at the end*/
  100% { top: auto; right: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
}
```

```css
.text {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: change 4s normal 0s infinite;
  top: auto; right: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes change {
  25% { top: auto; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: auto; }
  50% { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: auto; left: auto; }
  75% { top: 0; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0; }
  100% { top: auto; right: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text">Hai</h3>
</div>
```

But if you wanted the text to slide, you can use this:

```
@keyframes change {
    /* Change from bottom left to bottom right a quarter way through*/
  25% { left: 0; top: 100%; transform: translate(0%, -100%); }
    /* Change from bottom right to top right half way through*/
  50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%); }
    /* Change from top right to top left three quarters through*/
  75% { left: 100%; top: 0; transform: translate(-100%, 0%); }
    /* Change from top left to bottom left at the end*/
  100% { left: 0; top: 0; transform: translate(-0%, 0%); }
}
```

```css
.text {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: change 4s normal 0s infinite;
  left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(-0%, 0%);
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes change {
  25% { left: 0; top: 100%; transform: translate(0%, -100%); }
  50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%); }
  75% { left: 100%; top: 0; transform: translate(-100%, 0%); }
  100% { left: 0; top: 0; transform: translate(-0%, 0%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text">Hai</h3>
</div>
```

(In the example I have scaled down the div's size but this method will work with whatever height and width)

Comment: @ShafeequeS How's my answer?

Comment: @vals It wasn't intentional. I actually found something similar on the internet, and copied/adapted from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295187/css-animate-a-div-with-absolute-positioning-from-left-0-to-right-0

Answer (score 4):

Here you go bro. Use keyframes to get the desired css animation effect.

```css
@keyframes square {
  0%    {top: 0; left: 0}
  25%   {top: 0; left: 100%;}
  50%   {top: 100%; left: 100%;}
  75%   {top: 100%; left: 0px;}
  100%  {top: 0px; left: 0px;}
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: square;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;">
  <h3>Hai</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that the text doesn't go to the bottom left or right, only slightly more than halfway. If you change `100px` to `200px` it goes outside the box (as revealed by giving the container a background-color). It would require getting the exact height and width of the text for this method to work, and the text size and length is likely to vary.

Comment: True, but I only made it go 100px in each direction so you could see the effect in the small preview box instead of having to scroll down.

Comment: Ah crap you are right, the text goes outside of the box.  @JamesDouglas

Comment: Thanks cup_of for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use left, top, and transforms:

```css
div {
   height: 400px;
   width:500px;
   border: solid 1px blue;
   position: relative;
}
h3 {
    background-color: tomato;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    animation: move 5s infinite linear;
    position: absolute;
}


@keyframes move {
    0% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(-0%, 0%);}
   25% { left: 0px; top: 100%; transform: translate(0%, -100%);}
   50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);}
   75% { left: 100%; top: 0%; transform: translate(-100%, -0%);}
   100% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(-0%, 0%);}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Hai</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks vals for your answer

Comment: Happy that it helped :-)